# What ring is the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-11})$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

Could anyone help me with this question?

I've the feeling that the answer is $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure at all and above all I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-11})$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the omission

Answer (score 1):

By $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-11})$ you actually mean :

$1+\sqrt{-11}=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ i.e., $\sqrt{-11}=-1$

But, $-1$ is already in $\mathbb{Z}$. So, only thing you have to look for is what does $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ mean?

So, what you have guessed is correct.

There are some gaps to be filled in my argument and i hope it would not be so difficult.